# Adding new line of formfields

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have these formfields:

```
<div class="input-group-option">

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group" id="add_aantal_huidig_div">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="add_aantal_huidig[]" name="add_aantal_huidig[]" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group" id="add_min_aantal_1_div">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="add_min_aantal_1[]" name="add_min_aantal_1">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="form-group" id="add_min_aantal_2_div">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="add_min_aantal_2" name="add_min_aantal_2[]" value="">
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I am using this script to create a new line of formfields when an user click on one of the formfield.

```
$(function(){

    $(document).on('focus', 'div.input-group-option:last-child input', function(){

        var sInputGroupHtml = $(this).parent().html();
        var sInputGroupClasses = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        $(this).parent().parent().append('<div class="'+sInputGroupClasses+'">'+sInputGroupHtml+'</div>');

    });
});
```

So the result after clicking is:
[image]

The problem I have now is that when a user clicks a formfield, only this formfield is copied and not the other formfields.
With this result:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<div class="input-group-option-container">
    <div class="input-group-option">

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group" id="add_aantal_huidig_div">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="add_aantal_huidig[]" name="add_aantal_huidig[]" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group" id="add_min_aantal_1_div">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="add_min_aantal_1[]" name="add_min_aantal_1">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group" id="add_min_aantal_2_div">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="add_min_aantal_2" name="add_min_aantal_2[]" value="">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
  $(function(){

    $(document).on('focus', 'div.input-group-option:last-child input', function(){
      var sInputGroupHtml = $('div.input-group-option:last-child').html();

      var sInputGroupClasses = $('div.input-group-option').attr('class');

      $('div.input-group-option').parent().append(`<div class="${sInputGroupClasses}">${sInputGroupHtml}</div>`);

    });
  });
```

style

```
    .input-group-option-container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
```

Comment: You are the best!!

Comment: if the last fields have data the data is also copied to the new fields. Please advice.